# xna / content pipeline / asset and screen management

Tags: vb.net, xna

I am new to XNA and this is a philosophical question. In most examples I have seen, game assets are defined as private class variables, loaded in the LoadContent method, and then drawn with the Draw method. If I have a large game with a lot of screens, there could be quite a bit of declarations at the top of this class.

With that said, here are my questions

1. Should I use the content pipeline over Texture2D.FromFile().
2. What are the advantages other than faster loading.
3. Should I call Content.Load(Of T)([some asset name]) outside the LoadContent() sub.

How are you handling loading assets for different screens? Are you declaring all assets at the top?

Thanks in advanced,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

Using the Content Pipeline allows you to compile your textures with your binary, which saves space, load time, and protects your assets from editing/unauthorized use if you care about that. On the flipside, if you wanted an asset to be editable (like texture packs), `FromFile()` is effective. The file must exist in the expected directory with normal use of course.

It is good practice but ultimately your decision on where you choose to load content. Remember that content loading requires reading from disk, which is not something you want to be doing every frame for sure, and not really something we like doing during the game. You will want to set up your Game State Management so that content can be loaded completely during loading screens or game startup and not during the game itself. Of course, this is precisely what level loading screens are for! If you're very clever you can sneak loading in during pauses in gameplay, a la Metroid Prime's 'door loading'. Depending on the scope and assets of your game, though, you shouldn't really need to load dynamically like that.

Finally, about dumping assets: the answer is the great trope of OO programming: abstraction. If you have trouble organizing members then move them into an inherited class or a subclass as necessary (and only when sensible). In my game design I rarely have more than 2 `Texture2D`s, 1 `SoundBank`, and perhaps a `VertexBuffer`/`IndexBuffer` per class. If I have designed things well, these are stored in a base class like "Sprite" from which any visual objects inherit. In my latest set of tools, I've gone one level deeper, so now it looks like "`Player.base`(which is Sprite)`.Animation.Texture`" if you want to access the actual texture... but you don't need to because all animation/drawing is handled completely by the `Animation` class and updated by Sprite along with `Position`, `Rotation`, `Scale`, `Bounding`, etc.

So, break down your game into objects. If you are storing a `Texture2D PlayerTex` and `Vector2 PlayerPos` in your `Game` class and in `Draw` you are drawing `PlayerTex` at `PlayerPos`, you are not taking advantage of OO programming. Store `PlayerTex` and `PlayerPos` in a `Player` class which also defines every other aspect and behavior (methods) of the player. Now all you need in `Game` is `Player myPlayer`, and in `Draw` you call `myPlayer.Draw(SpriteBatch .. etc)`. You can take it even further! Here are some classes pretty much every game will have: `Entity` (base class of all dynamic objects), `Level` (stores scenery and `Entities` of each level and handles their interaction), `GameScreen` (stores and increments its `Level` member upon completion of each), `ScreenManager` (stores a stack of `Screen`s to update, like `GameScreen`, but also `MenuScreen`, `PauseScreen`, `LoadingScreen`)... The list goes on. At this point all your `Game1` class does is update `ScreenManager`, and if you inherit `ScreenManager` from `IDrawableGameComponent`, you don't even have to do that.

I hope I haven't dived too far into the deep end of OO 101, but if you're having trouble keeping track of all the members of your main class, you should start to break things down. It's a fundamental OO skill.

If all else fails, learn to use the `#region <name>`/`#endregion` tags liberally. Honestly, use them anyway, they make everything better.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Even though I use regions, it just seems like an aweful lot of code in one place. I found something called screenmanager which looks like something I should look into it.